# Android Intent Clear Top not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to hit an intent to my HomeScreenActivity and clear all the activity that are alive in the Stack, below is the intent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HomeScreenActivity.class);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    }
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

The stack is not getting cleared and when i press the back key, all the previous activity are shown, which is not the expected result.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP instead of TASK

Comment: Its still not clearing the Stack :(

Comment: It worked when I removed the other flags intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use both flags at the same time:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

First flag creates new activity when it isn't available in the current task (stack of activities) or reuses existing one. Second flag clears a task associated with requested activity.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
```

Comment: Your answer link is recursive to this page.